# from flash, run php file to refresh xml file without popup window

Tags: php, actionscript-3

From flash, run php file to refresh xml file without popup window there is no passing of any data from flash to the php file or back to flash.just tying to run the php that writes an xml file.

forgot to add this

```
var phpPath:String;
var sendHeader:URLRequestHeader;
var sendReq:URLRequest;
var sendLoader:URLLoader;
```

tried this, doesn't seem to work.  maybe I need to add so

```
mybuton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_EnterFrameHandler_4);

function fl_EnterFrameHandler_4(event:Event):void
{


phpPath = "http://www.mysite.com/my_xml_file.php";


sendHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type","application/octet-stream");
sendReq = new URLRequest(phpPath);
sendReq.requestHeaders.push(sendHeader);
sendReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

}
```

Comment: What's the backtick doing after 'sendReq.requestHeaders.push(sendHeader)'

Comment: just a mistake. got it thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you create your URLRequest, you never actually send that request. You need to use [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) to do that:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(sendReq);
```

Comment: Darn, missed submitting the answer by 30 seconds :) PS: The other day I thought I noticed a class that could be used when you just want to hit the server (and not wait for a response...) but I can't find that now.

Comment: @SunilD. That would be [`sendToURL`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#sendToURL%28%29) :)